# How to capture a column values form SHOW SLAVE STATUS

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to capture a value of "seconds_behind_master" column.

> SHOW SLAVE STATUS;

How to achieve it ?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? That's not clear at all.

Comment: I need to capture the value of seconds_behind_master column. While querying the statement SHOW SLAVE STATUS in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a shell script or on the command line on Linux you could:

```
SECONDS_BEHIND=$(mysql -usome_user -psome_pass -e "show slave status" -E | grep "Seconds_Behind_Master:" | cut -d: -f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SECONDS=$(mysql -uuser -ppass -Pport -e"show slave status\G" grep Seconds_Behind_Master | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Please elaborate about what this code does rather than just pasting. Thanks!