# Show slave status where value = x

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

Is there a way to only show slave status when a 'value' is true? I am trying to create a Crystal Report that i then want to schedule with Crystal Server to email when the report contains data. I.e. When the slave is more then x number of seconds behind the master. In English, i want to:

```
show slave status
where seconds_behind_master > 100 or seconds_behind_master is null
```

I have found [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850240/how-to-capture-a-column-values-form-show-slave-status/) but i dont think/know how to begin with adding a shell command as a Crystal Report command, if it can even be done.

Is there any way to filter the returned data based on a WHERE or something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get around this, quite simply in fact.

I just created the command in Crystal with "Show slave status" so it included anything.  Then filtered and hid the details based on the criteria i mentioned in the OP on the "seconds_behind_master" field

**Suppress field based on the below formula in Crystal:**

not(
isnull({Command.Seconds_Behind_Master})
or
{Command.Seconds_Behind_Master} >100
)

Simple when you think about it...maybe too simple and that's why i didn't.  Hope it helps someone else one day.